# Using Keras LSTM to predict 10+ classes: inconsistent label outputs by model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, multiclass-classification

I am using keras bi-lstm to predict 14 classes.
Here is my label index:

```
label_index=`{'1':0,'2':1,'D':2,'7':3,'8':4,'9':5,'10':6,'11':7,'12':8,'13':9,'14':10,'15':11,'16':12,'17':13}`
```

Here is part of my model setting:

```
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))

model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The "14" in the Dense function is the number of classes. When I looked at the label distribution of `pred = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)`, I found this:

```
Counter({'1': 54,
         '10': 88,
         '11': 5,
         '12': 2,
         '13': 6,
         '14': 5,
         '3': 65,
         '4': 5,
         '5': 3,
         '6': 28,
         '7': 10,
         '8': 3,
         '9': 3})
```

Where did this "14" come from???? It's not in my index. And there was no "0"!  I guess in the multi-class situation, kera.predict cannot output zero. Should I deduct 1 for every element in my "pred"?

Comment: "D" is a pretty frequent class in the training, but it didn't appear in pred. Is pred producing labels or their indices?

Comment: I think your label index map is swapped. The keys are values and vice cersa

Comment: My following code is like this:    labels=[[label_index[item[0]]] for item in f] and then    labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))    . I swapped the map and it reported a key error on 'D'.